# How to use SPARQL on SQL triples

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-11

I'd like to combine triples from ontologies with data that was exposed via TDEs, to prevent having to expose the data both as TDE views, and as triples. However, subjects and predicates from TDE data don't behave as regular IRIs. I have learned that TDE view subjects are actually sql:rowIds (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/61679309/918496), but that knowledge hasn't helped me use them in a where clause, unless using an expensive filter expression.

I was hoping there is a way to run a query something like this:

```
select *
where {
  <http://marklogic.com/row/3B89C3F7B234C80F/00001E041393E29F> ?p ?o.
}
limit 10
```

Instead of doing something like this:

```
select *
where {
  ?s ?p ?o.
  filter( str(?s) = "4290175588661250063:33002857161375" )
}
limit 10
```

Note the fact that "4290175588661250063:33002857161375" doesn't quite seem to match http://marklogic.com/row/3B89C3F7B234C80F/00001E041393E29F, but that does appear to be the str value of the rowId.

Comment: Can You explain how You isolated this value to begin with that You show as the subject?  I'm wondering if perhaps a filter based on a cts query using cts:column-range-query or perhaps making use of cts:columnID - but would like to see your starting point.

Comment: I just ran `select str(?s) ?s
where {
  ?s ?p ?o.
}
limit 10`, and grabbed the first hit which happened to be an sql:rowId.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sql:rowId()` function to construct a row ID from the string representation.

Comment: Can you show a (hypothetical) sparql example of how that should work?

Comment: @John Snelson - it should be noted the sql:rowId() appears to be undocumented.

Comment: https://docs.marklogic.com/sql lists no reference